# SQL Multiple Joining with same fields

Tags: sql-server

I want to join two table but over two field that in other table. Two column from one table by different ids.
My table structure is below:

**Units**

```
+---+---------+----+
| Uid | UnitName
+---+--------------+
| 1   | Unit A     |   
| 2   | Unit B     |
| 3   | Unit C     |
+----+---------+---+
```

**Persons**

```
+---+---------+-------------------+------------+------+
| Pid | PerName          | PerUnit | PreviousPerUnit |
+---+---------+-------------------+------------+------+
| 1   | John             | 1       |    3            |
| 2   | Alice            | 2       |    1            |
| 3   | Mel              | 1       |    1            |
+----+---------+------------------+------------+------+
```

**So I want to output**

```
+---+---------+-------------------+------------+----+
| #  | PerName          | UnitName   | PreUnitName |
+---+---------+-------------------+------------+----+
| 1  | John             | Unit A     | Unit C      |
| 2  | Alice            | Unit B     | Unit A      |
| 3  | Mel              | Unit A     | Unit A      |
+----+---------+------------------+------------+----+
```

How can I get this output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT
    [#]         = p.Pid,
    Pername     = p.PerName,
    UnitName    = u1.UnitName,
    PerUnitName = u2.UnitName
FROM Persons p
INNER JOIN Units u1
    ON u1.Uid = p.PerUnit
INNER JOIN Units u2
    ON u2.Uid = p.PreviousPerUnit
```

Comment: Thanks Felix for ur answer. It's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT p.PerName,perUnitTable.UnitName,PreviousUnitTable.UnitName
FROM Person p
INNER JOIN Units perUnitTable ON p.PerUnit=perUnitTable.Uid
INNER JOIN Units PreviousUnitTable ON p.PerUnit=PreviousUnitTable.Uid
```

Comment: Thanks JaydipJ for ur answer. It's ok.